# iPython Notebook Pandas Not Plotting

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to produce a plot from a dataframe in iPython Notebook, but the command doesn't execute. The dataframe(StatePremiums) looks like this:

```
   index    StateCode   PremiumAdultIndividualAge30 YearlyAverage
0   0       AK         633                          7596
1   1       AK         755                          9060
2   2       AK         916                          10992
3   3       AK         803                          9636
4   4       AK         785                          9420
```

When I try to plot using the following line, the kernel doesn't execute, it just keeps running without end. This isn't a display/show issue.

```
StatePremiumAverages.plot(kind="barh",x=StatePremiumAverages["StateCode"],  
                      title="Average Yearly Health Premiums for Individuals, Age 30", legend=False)
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Please post `StatePremiumAverages.info()`.

Comment: If you run `df = StatePremiumAverages.head()`, does `df.plot(kind="barh",x="StateCode")` work?

Comment: Have you done `%matplotlib inline`? It may be showing the plot in a separate window and blocking execution.

Comment: `%matplotlib notebook` is a far better option @ThomasK ;)

Comment: @unutbu     <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 89909 entries, 0 to 89908
Data columns (total 4 columns):
index                          89909 non-null int64
StateCode                      89909 non-null object
PremiumAdultIndividualAge30    89390 non-null float64
YearlyAverage                  89390 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 3.4+ MB Yes, that did work, although now plt.show() doesn't process. Why did creating a separate df work?

Comment: @ThomasK Can you explain what that is, and why that matters? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use %matplotlib inline as the first line of your notebook.  The following works for me:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
StatePremiumAverages = pd.DataFrame({
    'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'StateCode': ['AK', 'AK', 'AK', 'AK', 'AK'],
    'PremiumAdultIndividualAge30' : [633, 755, 916, 803, 785],
    'YearlyAverage' : [7596, 9060, 10992, 9636, 9420]
    })
StatePremiumAverages.plot(kind="barh",x=StatePremiumAverages["StateCode"],  
    title="Average Yearly Health Premiums for Individuals, Age 30", legend=False)
```